# Sharing SignalR hub with ASP.NET Website and a Web API Mobile Backend

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, asp.net-web-api, signalr

I've set up SignalR Realtime communication for my ASP.NET based website. However, I need to know if it's possible to share the same SignalR Hub with a separate Mobile Backend Project which deals with the same server and database. Basically like accessing the facebook's inbox through web and mobile at the same time?

That would be a ASP.NET Web project and a Mobile Client connected to one hub.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to find **SignalR for Android**, I suggest the following working link for your to start

- [SignalR/java-client at GitHub](https://github.com/SignalR/java-client)

You can refer to the following sample code (this is from my question on SO about **SignalR for Android**: [SignalR for Android: how can I pass dynamic class to SubscriptionHandler1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31468517/signalr-how-can-i-pass-dynamic-class-to-subscriptionhandler1)

```
public <T> void startSignalR(String transport, String serverUrl, final String userName, final Class<T> tClass) {

    Platform.loadPlatformComponent(new AndroidPlatformComponent());
    Credentials credentials = new Credentials() {
        @Override
        public void prepareRequest(Request request) {
            request.addHeader(HEADER_KEY_USERNAME, userName);
        }
    };

    mConnection = new HubConnection(serverUrl);
    mConnection.setCredentials(credentials);
    mHub = mConnection.createHubProxy(SERVER_HUB_CHAT);

    if (transport.equals("ServerSentEvents")) {
         mTransport = new ServerSentEventsTransport(mConnection.getLogger());
    } else if (transport.equals("LongPolling")) {
         mTransport = new LongPollingTransport(mConnection.getLogger());
    }

    mAwaitConnection = mConnection.start(mTransport);

    try {
        mAwaitConnection.get();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {      
        e.printStackTrace();      
        return;
    } catch (ExecutionException e) { 
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }

    mHub.on("broadcastMessage",
            new SubscriptionHandler1<Object>() {
                @Override
                public void run(final Object msg) {
                    final String finalMsg;
                    Gson gson = new Gson();
                    Object object = gson.fromJson(msg.toString(), tClass);
                    Field[] fields = object.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
                    for (int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
                        try {
                            System.out.println("Value = " + fields[i].get(object));                                
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }                        
                }
            }
            , Object.class);

    ...
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @WaiHaLee: thanks for your comment. I have updated with sample code.

Comment: Does this library uses websockets ?