# SignalR integration in android studio

Tags: android, signalr, signalr.client

I use signalR lib in my project. but I was not able to compile libs of https://github.com/SignalR/java-client on my own - I found them in internet. But it seems like there are not full (WebsocketTransport is missing)

When I compile https://github.com/SignalR/java-client, i get two libs, and paste them to my app.gradle -

```
compile files ('libs/signalr-client-sdk.jar')
compile files ('libs/signalr-client-sdk-android.jar')
```

Progects build suckesfully, butwhen I press run - it fails.
Here is stack trace -

```
  UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version (0034.0000)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse0(DirectClassFile.java:472)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse(DirectClassFile.java:406)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parseToInterfacesIfNecessary(DirectClassFile.java:388)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.getMagic(DirectClassFile.java:251)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:704)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:673)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$300(Main.java:83)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:602)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:510)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:280)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
...while parsing microsoft/aspnet/signalr/client/Action.class
```

1 error; aborting
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

I do not know what to do. I even tried to compile forks of this project, but have got the same result, same error. Need any help, Thanks!

**UPDATE**

in my Application class i have

```
Platform.loadPlatformComponent(new AndroidPlatformComponent());
```

in my app.gradle:

```
compile files ('libs/gson-2.2.2.jar')
compile files ('libs/signalr-client-sdk.jar')
compile files ('libs/signalr-client-sdk-android.jar')
```

in my code I use

```
connection.start(new ServerSentEventsTransport(connection.getLogger())).get();
```

I also create lots of hubs on this connection, nad call methods. All works, but connection always dissapears, if i do not do anything with device more then for 30 seconds. And I do not have any callbacks that the connection was lost\disconected or anything like that - I log all this stuff. But I think it can happen because i have pretty old libs, i googled - as I mention in this question i did not menaged to build signalR project to receive more recent libs

Comment: @BNK, what code exactly do you need? gradle file?

Comment: The code of how you call/use SignalR in your Android project.

Comment: You can refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32288357/sharing-signalr-hub-with-asp-net-website-and-a-web-api-mobile-backend/32291532#32291532

Comment: @BNK , updated answeir

Comment: Take a look at my answer :)

Comment: Does my answer work for your question or not?

Comment: @BNK , no, I used pretty same approach, and I still loose connection, as I wrote in update

Comment: Do you mean that your app worked successfully, however, sometimes the connection between it and server app lost?

Comment: @BNK , seems like I have found 2 bugs and make it work, still testing. I have got crashes periodically in WebSocketTransport, because i received too long message - and it just splits into two parts - and the second part was ',' ! And that is the shit! SignalR fails, and call for disconnect.

Comment: Second bug is that websokets did not managed to properly set headers. I have done that manually. maybe when i will fix and check for few days, I will write full answeir

Comment: Looks like Android's SignalR does not support WebSocketTransport

Comment: with those 2 fixes it works, somehow , but still buggy

Comment: Buggy? Sorry I don't understand that word :-)

Comment: have you tried LongPolling yet?

Comment: buggy - it is version with some bugs :) LongPolling and ServerSendEvents seems to work not so fast as WebSockets. So i need websockets in my app

Comment: I have not ever tried Websocket successfully with SignalR for Android :-)

Comment: But for me SSE transport has a bug too - i "loose" connection if i do not do any operations for more than a minute. But connection tehnically still exists, but i checked logs on server - nothing comes in, unfortunatly. With websockets i do not havbe such bug

Comment: IMO, you can try LongPolling.

Answer (score 10):

Here is my working basic code, hope this helps!

```
package com.example.simplesignalrclient;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Binder;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

import microsoft.aspnet.signalr.client.Credentials;
import microsoft.aspnet.signalr.client.Platform;
import microsoft.aspnet.signalr.client.SignalRFuture;
import microsoft.aspnet.signalr.client.http.Request;
import microsoft.aspnet.signalr.client.http.android.AndroidPlatformComponent;
import microsoft.aspnet.signalr.client.hubs.HubConnection;
import microsoft.aspnet.signalr.client.hubs.HubProxy;
import microsoft.aspnet.signalr.client.hubs.SubscriptionHandler1;
import microsoft.aspnet.signalr.client.transport.ClientTransport;
import microsoft.aspnet.signalr.client.transport.ServerSentEventsTransport;

public class SignalRService extends Service {
    private HubConnection mHubConnection;
    private HubProxy mHubProxy;
    private Handler mHandler; // to display Toast message
    private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder(); // Binder given to clients

public SignalRService() {
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    int result = super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    startSignalR();
    return result;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    mHubConnection.stop();
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // Return the communication channel to the service.
    startSignalR();
    return mBinder;
}

/**
 * Class used for the client Binder.  Because we know this service always
 * runs in the same process as its clients, we don't need to deal with IPC.
 */
public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
    public SignalRService getService() {
        // Return this instance of SignalRService so clients can call public methods
        return SignalRService.this;
    }
}

/**
 * method for clients (activities)
 */
public void sendMessage(String message) {
    String SERVER_METHOD_SEND = "Send";
    mHubProxy.invoke(SERVER_METHOD_SEND, message);
}    

private void startSignalR() {
    Platform.loadPlatformComponent(new AndroidPlatformComponent());

    Credentials credentials = new Credentials() {
        @Override
        public void prepareRequest(Request request) {
            request.addHeader("User-Name", "BNK");
        }
    };

    String serverUrl = "http://192.168.1.100";
    mHubConnection = new HubConnection(serverUrl);
    mHubConnection.setCredentials(credentials);
    String SERVER_HUB_CHAT = "ChatHub";
    mHubProxy = mHubConnection.createHubProxy(SERVER_HUB_CHAT);
    ClientTransport clientTransport = new ServerSentEventsTransport(mHubConnection.getLogger());
    SignalRFuture<Void> signalRFuture = mHubConnection.start(clientTransport);

    try {
        signalRFuture.get();
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }

    String HELLO_MSG = "Hello from Android!";
    sendMessage(HELLO_MSG);

    String CLIENT_METHOD_BROADAST_MESSAGE = "broadcastMessage";
    mHubProxy.on(CLIENT_METHOD_BROADAST_MESSAGE,
            new SubscriptionHandler1<CustomMessage>() {
                @Override
                public void run(final CustomMessage msg) {
                    final String finalMsg = msg.UserName + " says " + msg.Message;
                    // display Toast message
                    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), finalMsg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
            , CustomMessage.class);
}
}
```

Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private final Context mContext = this;
private SignalRService mService;
private boolean mBound = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setClass(mContext, SignalRService.class);
    bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    // Unbind from the service
    if (mBound) {
        unbindService(mConnection);
        mBound = false;
    }
    super.onStop();
}    

public void sendMessage(View view) {
    if (mBound) {
        // Call a method from the SignalRService.
        // However, if this call were something that might hang, then this request should
        // occur in a separate thread to avoid slowing down the activity performance.
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);            
        if (editText != null && editText.getText().length() > 0) {                
            String message = editText.getText().toString();
            mService.sendMessage(message);
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Defines callbacks for service binding, passed to bindService()
 */
private final ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className,
                                   IBinder service) {
        // We've bound to SignalRService, cast the IBinder and get SignalRService instance
        SignalRService.LocalBinder binder = (SignalRService.LocalBinder) service;
        mService = binder.getService();
        mBound = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
        mBound = false;
    }
};
}
```

CustomMessage Class:

```
public class CustomMessage {
    public String UserName;
    public String Message;
}
```

Comment: what package does `Service` live in? can you please include your imports? Android Studio cant find it and my refs to signalr are ok because i'm able to compile with a ref to `AndroidPlatformComponent`

Comment: thanks; helps the n00bs (of which i an one )get thru the day

Comment: perhaps you could help with this one
`java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: microsoft.aspnet.signalr.client.transport.NegotiationException: There was a problem in the negotiation with the server` - I'm forcing SSE on the connection via `ServerSentEventsTransport` - the signalr endpoint is working fine as I'm using a javascript client to connect to it successfully. any ideas?

Comment: @wal For that exception, pls check if the hub name is correct or not

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90956/discussion-between-wal-and-bnk).

Comment: @BNK  Could you please tell me how could i call the service from other activity. I start my service in my main activity and its work fine. Now i want to call this service from ChatActivity.

Comment: I am getting the same error as : java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: microsoft.aspnet.signalr.client.transport.NegotiationException: There was a problem in the negotiation with the server

Answer (score 9):

**JUST TO HELP SOMEONE WHO GOT STUCK LIKE ME.**

I was trying to get my SingalR to work.
I followed the answer given but service was not firing.
This was my first project to implement a service like SignalRService.
So I did not know.

I added `<service>` entry to my manifest file then everything started working.

```
    <service android:name=".SignalRService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
    </service>
```

Thanks a lot BNK