# How to receive Messages in chat App using signalR in Android

Tags: android, signalr

hello i am new in signalR i am making one chating app with using signalR i take reference from [SignalR integration in android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32505390/signalr-integration-in-android-studio) here with the help of this i able to send the messages to the chat group but i am not able to receive messages i read lots of Q&A here but i am not able to solve this problem i paste here my code and please anyone tell me how do i receive message from the server.following is my code.

Activity main

```
   package myapp.chatapp;

import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.ServiceConnection;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.gson.JsonElement;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import microsoft.aspnet.signalr.client.MessageReceivedHandler;
import microsoft.aspnet.signalr.client.Platform;
import microsoft.aspnet.signalr.client.http.android.AndroidPlatformComponent;
import microsoft.aspnet.signalr.client.hubs.HubConnection;
import microsoft.aspnet.signalr.client.hubs.HubProxy;
import microsoft.aspnet.signalr.client.hubs.SubscriptionHandler2;
import microsoft.aspnet.signalr.client.transport.ClientTransport;
import microsoft.aspnet.signalr.client.transport.LongPollingTransport;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SignalRService.Something {

    private StringBuilder mLog;

    private ListView mTestCaseList;

    private Spinner mTestGroupSpinner;

    private HubConnection mHubConnection;
    private HubProxy mHubProxy;

    private final Context mContext = this;
    private SignalRService mService;
    private SignalRService mMessageResive;
    private boolean mBound = false;

    ListView list_item;
    EditText editText;


    ArrayList<String> listItems;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    ClientTransport transport;

    private Handler mHandler; // to display Toast message

    private Thread t;

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        // don't restart the activity. Just process the configuration change
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClass(mContext, SignalRService.class);
        bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);


        editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
        ImageButton btn = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btn);
        list_item = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_item);
        listItems = new ArrayList<String>();
        /*listItems.add("First Item - added on Activity Create");*/
       /* adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listItems);*/

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(mContext,R.layout.custom_list, R.id.textView,listItems);
        list_item.setAdapter(adapter);

        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed( new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                handler.postDelayed( this, 1000 );
            }
        }, 1000 );






        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                listItems.add(editText.getText().toString());
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                sendMessage(view);
            }
        });




    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        // Unbind from the service
        if (mBound) {
            unbindService(mConnection);
            mBound = false;
        }
        super.onStop();
    }

    public void sendMessage(View view) {
        if (mBound) {

            String message = editText.getText().toString();
            String email = "kn@yopmail.com";
            String name = "Kunal From Android";
            String group ="1";
            mService.sendMessage(name,email,group,message);
            editText.setText("");
            // Call a method from the SignalRService.
            // However, if this call were something that might hang, then this request should
            // occur in a separate thread to avoid slowing down the activity performance.
            /*EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
            if (editText != null && editText.getText().length() > 0) {

            }*/
        }
    }

    public void setmMessageResive(JsonElement jsonElement)
    {


        listItems.add(10, String.valueOf(jsonElement));


    }


    /**
     * Defines callbacks for service binding, passed to bindService()
     */
    private final ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName componentName, IBinder iBinder) {
            // We've bound to SignalRService, cast the IBinder and get SignalRService instance
            SignalRService.LocalBinder binder = (SignalRService.LocalBinder) iBinder;
            mService = binder.getService();
            mBound = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
            mBound = false;
        }
    };



    @Override
    public void doSomething(String msg) {

        listItems.add(msg);

    }
}
```

Service code

```
    package myapp.chatapp;

import android.app.Service;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothClass;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Binder;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.gson.JsonElement;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import microsoft.aspnet.signalr.client.Action;
import microsoft.aspnet.signalr.client.Credentials;
import microsoft.aspnet.signalr.client.LogLevel;
import microsoft.aspnet.signalr.client.MessageReceivedHandler;
import microsoft.aspnet.signalr.client.Platform;
import microsoft.aspnet.signalr.client.SignalRFuture;
import microsoft.aspnet.signalr.client.http.Request;
import microsoft.aspnet.signalr.client.http.android.AndroidPlatformComponent;
import microsoft.aspnet.signalr.client.hubs.HubConnection;
import microsoft.aspnet.signalr.client.hubs.HubProxy;
import microsoft.aspnet.signalr.client.hubs.SubscriptionHandler1;
import microsoft.aspnet.signalr.client.hubs.SubscriptionHandler2;
import microsoft.aspnet.signalr.client.hubs.SubscriptionHandler4;
import microsoft.aspnet.signalr.client.transport.ClientTransport;
import microsoft.aspnet.signalr.client.transport.LongPollingTransport;
import microsoft.aspnet.signalr.client.transport.ServerSentEventsTransport;

/**
 * Created by NULLPLEX7 on 11/28/2017.
 */

public class SignalRService extends Service {
    private HubConnection mHubConnection;
    private HubProxy mHubProxy;
    private Handler mHandler; // to display Toast message
    private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder(); // Binder given to clients

    ClientTransport transport;

    registerListener registerListener;

    private MainActivity setmMessageResive;

    public  Something list;

    public SignalRService() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        int result = super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        startSignalR();
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        mHubConnection.stop();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // Return the communication channel to the service.
        startSignalR();
        return mBinder;
    }



    /**
     * Class used for the client Binder.  Because we know this service always
     * runs in the same process as its clients, we don't need to deal with IPC.
     */
    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        public SignalRService getService() {
            // Return this instance of SignalRService so clients can call public methods
            return SignalRService.this;
        }
    }

    /**
     * method for clients (activities)
     */
    public void sendMessage(String name, String email, String group, String msg ) {
        String SERVER_METHOD_SEND = "BroadCastMessage";
        mHubProxy.invoke(SERVER_METHOD_SEND, name,email,group,msg);
    }

    private void startSignalR() {
        Platform.loadPlatformComponent(new AndroidPlatformComponent());

        Credentials credentials = new Credentials() {
            @Override
            public void prepareRequest(Request request) {
                request.addHeader("User-Name", "BNK");
            }
        };

        String serverUrl = "myurlhere";
        mHubConnection = new HubConnection(serverUrl);
        mHubConnection.setCredentials(credentials);
        String SERVER_HUB_CHAT = "ChatHub";
        mHubProxy = mHubConnection.createHubProxy(SERVER_HUB_CHAT);
        ClientTransport clientTransport = new ServerSentEventsTransport(mHubConnection.getLogger());
        SignalRFuture<Void> signalRFuture = mHubConnection.start(clientTransport);


        mHubProxy.subscribe(this);

        transport = new LongPollingTransport(mHubConnection.getLogger());

        mHubConnection.start(transport);


          /* ****new codes here**** */
        /* ****seems useless but should be here!**** */
        mHubProxy.subscribe(new Object() {
            @SuppressWarnings("unused")
            public void newMessage(final String message, final String messageId, final String chatId,
                                   final String senderUserId, final String fileUrl, final String replyToMessageId) {


            }
        });

        try {

            signalRFuture.get();

        }catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }




        mHubProxy.on("receiveGroupMessage",
                new SubscriptionHandler4<String, String, String, String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void run(final String name,final String msg ,final String avtar,final String date ) {
                        final String finalMsg = name + " says " + msg;
                        /*final String finalMsg =  msg;*/
                        // display Toast message
                        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {

                                list.doSomething(msg);

                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
                , String.class,String.class,String.class,String.class);




             mHubConnection.received(new MessageReceivedHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onMessageReceived(final JsonElement json) {
                Log.e("receiveGroupMessage ", json.toString());
                mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+json, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }
        });



    }
    public interface Something
    {
        void doSomething(String msg);
    }

}
```

i read on stack overflow that in `onMessageReceived` i get the server responses but i did not get any response here . **I want  when any one send message  in group from web i want that message in my chat app**  someone suggest me that i need to create Event listener but i don't no how to create it . please tell me how do i get messages in my chat app.

```
   mHubProxy.on("receiveGroupMessage",
                new SubscriptionHandler4<String, String, String, String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void run(final String name,final String msg ,final String avtar,final String date ) {
                        final String finalMsg = name + " says " + msg;
                        /*final String finalMsg =  msg;*/
                        // display Toast message
                        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {

                                list.doSomething(msg);

                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
                , String.class,String.class,String.class,String.class);
```

i thought that i got messages here but execution not go inside the Run.

***Any Help is Welcome***